# Shopware 5, extjs bar chart Y axis issue

Tags: extjs, shopware5

In Shopware 5.7, I plot a chart through ext.js where y and x axis values ​​come from db table. The chart show random behaviors on the Y axis.

Please check the images to understand. It works perfectly until a certain value of y (ex 80) but after that bars value are not aligned with y-axis

I don't have any clue about this random behavior. Can I get a help from here?.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWLJ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

A function which fetch the maximum value available in the data object and assign it to the maximum property of y-axis solve my problem.

```
function getYMaximum()
    {
        var dataArray = me.getStore().data.items;
        var yMaximum = 100;
        for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(parseInt(dataArray[i].data.amount, 10) > yMaximum)
            {
                yMaximum = dataArray[i].data.amount;
            }
        }
        return yMaximum;
    }
```